# Can a library call invoke more than one system call?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I understand that, for example, calling the library function `printf` invokes the `write(2)` system call.

My question is: Is there a library call that can invoke more than one system call? In other words: Do system calls *always* map 1:1 to library calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 1:1 map from system calls to library calls and vice versa.

For example, most if not all arithmetic functions (*e.g.* [`sin`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sin.html)) don’t call any system calls; others such as [`posix_spawn`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) use multiple system calls.

Going the other way, some system calls such as [`init_module`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html) don’t have any corresponding library call and need to be called “manually” through [`syscall`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html).

Answer (score 2):

Counter-example [`getpwent`(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) invokes many system calls