# How are system call functions linked to an executable?

Tags: gcc, system-calls, dynamic-linking

Say I write a non-sensical program that features a single system call, `open`:

```c
#include <fcntl.h> 

void main()
{
    int hi = open("does not exist", 0);
}
```

When I compile the program and issue an `ldd` command on the output, I get the following:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffddd741000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6835328000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6835584000)
```

I only recognize the `libc.so.6` link, but I don't recognize the others.

Does one of these other libraries contain kernel system calls? Or is it possible that system call functions are statically linked? (seems unlikely).

Comment: Hmm, the API is provided by libc itself, right? `nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep -w open`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657036/where-is-linux-vdso-so-1-present-on-the-file-system

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400621/what-is-lib64-ld-linux-x86-64-so-2-and-why-can-it-be-used-to-execute-file

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396987/is-the-vdso-shared-library-linux-vdso-so-the-library-that-contains-the-kernel/397014#397014

Comment: @Quasímodo you were right! I assumed libc.so only contained standard C library functions, not POSIX system calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System calls aren’t directly visible as functions, and they aren’t linked as such. Each architecture defines its own way of invoking system calls; on 64-bit x86, [it involves a specific CPU instruction, `SYSCALL`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422878/86440).

The C library provides wrappers for most system calls (and [a generic system call function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) for the few unwrapped system calls), and that’s what your program links to.

The other libraries linked in your program are [the dynamic linker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400621/86440) and [the vDSO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/396987/86440).

Comment: So I'm somewhat confused. Correct me if I'm wrong, but system calls (e.g. open) are not part of the standard C library, yet the libc.so.6 still defines these functions? I assumed libc.so was reserved only for the standard C library.

Comment: `open` is [defined in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and is part of the standard C library. Most system calls implement a standard function; [some standard functions use multiple system calls, and many use none at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/615872/86440).

Comment: `libc.so.6` (the GNU C library) implements more than the strict C standard, *e.g.* [it has a wrapper for `clone`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html).

Comment: That solves my confusion then. I assumed the libc.so library would only include library definitions per some C standard. i.e. no POSIX functions.